# Mock pyodbc connection

Tags: python, mocking, pyodbc

I have the following snippet for my class.

```
class Sql_Workflow_Connector():

def __init__(self, server, database, username, password, sql_driver):
    self.server = server
    self.database = database
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=sql_driver, server=self.server,
                               port=1433, database=self.database, uid=self.username, pwd=self.password)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

I would like to start unit testing using pytest for this.

I need to mock out the connection and the cursor.
How do I go about doing this? As I would like to test **init** and the following calls sql functions using the mock connection and cursor.

Currently I my implemtation is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a solution you can implement using ***pytest***?  Does something like this work for your situation:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _mock_db_connection(mocker, db_connection):
    mocker.patch('db.database.dbc', db_connection)
    return True
```

I took this solution from here: [Pytest mock db connection](https://medium.com/@mariusz.raczynski2/pytest-mock-how-to-mock-your-database-connection-5c84a5a0bfc3)